# Sending Email using MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an App. registered as multi-tenant in azure, configured to allow access to users from other tenants including personal accounts etc..
But it fails when I tried to send using an external personal account. However it is working fine on the tenant members.

My question is, is it required for an external user to have an Exchange License to send email using the Graph API via my app?

If I'm sending using the application scope sendMail, does the user I used to send the email from needs to have a valid exhange license?

Thanks!

I need some experienced opinions or links to a helpful articles about my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the user you are using to send the email using application permission must have a valid Exchange license.

Also, user has to be part of your tenant while using the application permission otherwise it will just throw 404 not found

Comment: the second statement doesn't make sense for multitenant application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, user should be licensed. And to be accessed with personal accounts your application should be registered with audience as "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-register-app-v2